# How to fix ngx-datatable rows so they will appear?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

ngx datable won't display the rows, only the columns title.
data is updated but not bind to the rows in html.

html :

```
<div class="columns">
        <div class="column col-12">
                <ngx-datatable
                [rows]="rows"
                [columns]="columns"
                [rowHeight]="50">
                </ngx-datatable>
        </div>
</div>
```

typescript:

```
export class CurrencyResultsComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() amount: number;
  @Input() countryName: string;
  @Input() rates: Rate[];
  @Input() selectedcountry: string;

  public columns = [
    { amount: 'Amount' },
    { name: 'Country' },
  ];

  rows: DispRate[] = [];

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.rates && changes.rates.currentValue !== changes.rates.previousValue)  {
      for (const key of Object.keys(this.rates)) {
        const dataObj = {
          'amount': this.rates[key] * this.amount,
          'name': key
        };
        this.rows.push(dataObj);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

expected: table displayed
actual: No data to display

Comment: Try  `this.rows=[...this.rows];` after the `for-of` loop, it wiil update the binding to rows of `ngx datable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `this.rows=[...this.rows];` after the `for-of` loop, it will update the binding to rows of ngx-datable